# How to silence internal boost deprecated messages

Tags: c++, boost

I'm porting my code from boost 1.67 to boost 1.74 (debian buster->bullseye).

When I compile I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/config/header_deprecated.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/detail/no_exceptions_support.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp:20,
                 from /home/stew/mycode.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/detail/no_exceptions_support.hpp:17:1: note: ‘#pragma message: This header is deprecated. Use <boost/core/no_exceptions_support.hpp> instead.’
   17 | BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<boost/core/no_exceptions_support.hpp>")
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: note: ‘#pragma message: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.’
   36 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I get that headers get deprecated.  I'm happy to change

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>                         -> #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/detail/no_exceptions_support.hpp> -> #include <boost/core/no_exceptions_support.hpp>
```

However the problem isn't in my code.  It's in `<boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>`.  I'm getting errors like these for each instance of including any of these headers:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser/detail/parser.hpp:7,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser/detail/read.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp:16:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: note: ‘#pragma message: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.’
   36 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


In file included from /usr/include/boost/math/tools/cxx03_warn.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/math/constants/constants.hpp:11:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: note: ‘#pragma message: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.’
   36 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/sp_thread_sleep.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/yield_k.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_gcc_atomic.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock.hpp:42,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_pool.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/time_traits.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/timer_queue_ptime.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:25:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: note: ‘#pragma message: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.’
   36 | BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a way to silence boost's internal warnings without patching boost itself?

I know I can `-DBOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS` to avoid the `bind` warning, but what about the `detail/no_exceptions_support.hpp` issue?

Comment: If you are using cmake, you can `target_include_directories(YourTarget SYSTEM PUBLIC PATH_TO_BOOST)` https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: I am indeed using cmake.  I don't think there is any conflict between versions of boost and messing up include paths.  I'm building in a debian bullseye chroot with the debian packaged boost 1.74 as a system library and is the only version of boost available to the build system.

Comment: Yes yes, it is not to prevent conflicts, it is to tell CMake that this is a SYSTEM library and then it should ignore the warnings.

Comment: Ah, good idea.  I have about 350 affected targets and the project builds on several architectures, so I wonder if there is a way to add that `SYSTEM` property to the `Boost::boost` target.  Good place for me to do some research.  On our installs, boost is installed in `/usr/include` which I would have suspected is implicitly considered a system path.

Comment: Oh actually, that wouldn't work.  These aren't really warnings, they are preprocessor `#pragma message`s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just have a look at

boost/config/header_deprecated.hpp:

```
#ifndef BOOST_CONFIG_HEADER_DEPRECATED_HPP_INCLUDED
#define BOOST_CONFIG_HEADER_DEPRECATED_HPP_INCLUDED

//  Copyright 2017 Peter Dimov.
//
//  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
//
//  See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
//  http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt
//
//  BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED("<alternative>")
//
//  Expands to the equivalent of
//    BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE("This header is deprecated. Use <alternative> instead.")
//
//  Note that this header is C compatible.

#include <boost/config/pragma_message.hpp>

#if defined(BOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS)
# define BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED(a)
#else
# define BOOST_HEADER_DEPRECATED(a) BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE("This header is deprecated. Use " a " instead.")
#endif

#endif // BOOST_CONFIG_HEADER_DEPRECATED_HPP_INCLUDED
```

So add -DBOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS to your compile flags and the boost deprecation warnings should no longer be shown.

I am doing this in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
  # ignore BOOST deprecated headers
  add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS")
  add_definitions("-DBOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS")
```

And my build log is a lot less noisy now (Ubuntu 22.04 in my case)

Bye Gunther

Answer (score -1):

You can

- tell the library devs that the warnings are disruptive. The 'downstream' libraries should be updating to avoid the deprecated interface(s)
- look up workarounds for individual messages. E.g. globally adding the `BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS` define will silence all the `bind.hpp` warnings. Technically, you should prefer to use `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` but some libraries wouldn't work anymore (e.g. Boost Property Tree, at least for some backends).

Answer (score -1):

This has been driving me crazy too.  I finally just modified the internally referenced boost include files per the instruction.  In my case it was just four files and for most it was just a matter of commenting out unnecessary includes.  The files I modified are

- boost\geometry\index\detail\varray_detail.hpp
- boost\chrono\io\time_point_io.hpp
- boost\chrono\io\duration_io.hpp
- boost\range\metafunctions.hpp